# Copy cell values from excel files into a data frame in Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have few 100 excel files across folders and I need to copy a set of values at specific locations on the worksheet and each workbook will have a row of these values under the respective columns.  I am currently doing it this way :

```
  import glob
  import os
  import pandas as pd
  import xlrd
  os.chdir(directory location)
  frame=[]
  for x in glob.glob('**/**/*.xlsx'):
         workbook=xlrd.open_workbook(x)
        worksheet=workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
        value1= worksheet.cell(0,0).value
        value2= (worksheet.cell(1,1).value)
        df=pd.DataFrame(data=d,index=[0])
        frame.append(df)
dataa=pd.concat(frame)
```

I have about 75 such values and few 100 files across all folders. Currently the code is taking a long time to run. Is there an efficient way of doing this ?

Comment: did you measure _what_ causes the long time? Finding all athe excels? Reading each single excel? Copying cell values over into variables? Createing new dataframes? Concatting dataframes?

Comment: Hello Patrick, It is because of reading from each excel file, maybe specifying a range of worksheet instead of the entire worksheet shoud speed up the process?

Comment: if the reason it takes so long in from reading the excel file, copy them to an SSD and use that - thats probably the easiest way/only way to speedup IO-bound tasks

Comment: You could use multi-threading in order to speed up IO tasks